# How do I dynamically remove an element from a QML basic type list?

Tags: qt, qml

I've successfully added elements using

```
list.push(element)
```

But how do I remove them? I've tried the following, but none of them seem to work.

```
list.pop()
list.pop_front()
list.remove()
list.remove(int)
list.remove(element)
```

Comment: Is this a user-defined `list` property? What are the types of the elements you're storing?

Comment: Yes, it's a user-defined list and I'm storing AbstractSeries in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't remove individual items. According to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-list.html):

> Note that objects cannot be individually added to or removed from the list once created; to modify the contents of a list, it must be reassigned to a new list.

This means that the `pop` method most likely won't exist with the basic list type. (However, there *is* a `push` method.)

You'll be much better off using JavaScript arrays.

```
property var myArray: [1, 2, 3]

Component.onCompleted: {
    myArray.push(4);
    myArray.push(5);
    myArray.splice(1, 1)    // simulates a remove
    myArray.pop();          // pop last item

    console.debug(myArray)  // [1, 3, 4]
}
```

I've used `int`s here, but you can also store QML objects and other types as well. Using JavaScript arrays exposes your variables to most (if not all) of JavaScript's [Array functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Answer (score 9):

For people who always keep ending up on this page, like I did: I found a very hacky solution to remove an element from a `list<QtObject>`.

```
myList = Array.from(myList).filter(r => r !== elementIWant2Remove)
```

This is not very elegant, but it does the trick, if you need to remove an element.

Comment: When I saw your answer I immediately dismissed it because it converts my list to an array, but it's correct. Nice one.